# Calling a function in a typescript file from HTML doesn't show the returning variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

So i have this in my HTML

```
<h2>{{getCryptoName()}} price in {{getCurrencyName()}} is:</h2>
<ion-list>
    <div>
        {{getPrice()}}
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

The functions should be returning a string, which the do because I can see it on console but they don't display on the HTML

Functions:

```
getCryptoName(){
  this.nombresCrypto[this.Crypto];
}
```

```
getCurrencyName(){
  this.nombresCrypto[this.Crypto];
}
```

```
getPrice(){
  this.monedas[this.Crypto.toUpperCase()][this.Currency.toUpperCase()];
}
```

[This is the output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdOuS.png)

Any idea why it doesn't display on the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing your return statement in your functions.